# Having difficulty to find certain paper

Tags: number-theory, reference-request

I would be highly grateful if someone can help me with the following two things.

(1)Is any English translation of the following paper available? If yes , can someone provide the link here? I am not asking for the paper. I am asking for whether any English translation have been made.

*H. Hasse, Vorlesungen ¨uber Zahlentheorie, Second edition, Springer-Verlag, New York, $1964$ (L. Kronecker, $269–273; 440–442; $ K. Hensel, $438–439;$ *

(2) can someone please help me by telling where I can find the following paper. I tried a lot but couldn't find it in the web.

*Lectures of $1875/6$; K. Hensel, $1913, 304–305$. [First edition $1950$]*

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: (2) https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.chmm/1416338181

Comment: The Hasse "article" is actually a book. The title translates to "Lectures on Number Theory". I doubt a translation exists, but the material in it appears to be widely written about in other standard number theory texts. If I understand your pages correctly, you seem to be interested in quadratic reciprocity, binary quadratic forms, and Dedekind zeta functions. On the other hand, your Hensel pages seem to be about various sorts of primes in arithmetic progressions. Regardless, all these topics are in other works that might be easier to find. The Hensel reference is given in the other comment.

Comment: I'll add further that it might be a good idea to ask for references for the topics you are actually interested in, as opposed to tracking down these much older references --- unless of course you have a vested interested in tracking down these exact references for some reason.

Comment: Yeah . actually I want to track the exact reference

Comment: I am unable to download it from the given link @user. Can you help?

Comment: I have no problem with download. I cannot tell what is going wrong with your computer.

Comment: But it is just chapers information.

Comment: I have the English translation on my desk: Helmut Hasse, Number theory, Springer-Verlag, Berlin Heidelberg New York $1980$. It has $638$ pages and contains "everything" you are mentioning. Have fun to read it.

Comment: I also have that book..can you refer the page numbers in that book @ Dietrich Burde

Comment: If you click on the buttons "Previous/next chapter" you can browse the complete book. Or immediately choose "TOC" (this is abbreviation of "Table of Contents")

Comment: Yeah. I got it . Thanks @user